# Tradingview pinecode editor error : mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script

What is wrong with my code? I asked the chatgpt and their solution doesnot work tho

```
`//@version=2

// Define Order-Block parameters
blockSize = 100
minProfit = 0.01
stopLoss = 0.02

// Entry rule
if close > highest(close, blockSize) + minProfit
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long) 
else if close < lowest(close, blockSize) - minProfit
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

// Exit rule
if strategy.position_size > 0 and close < highest(close, blockSize) * (1 - stopLoss)
    strategy.close("Long")
else if strategy.position_size < 0 and close > lowest(close, blockSize) * (1 + stopLoss)
    strategy.close("Short")
```

`

I asked chatgpt and browse internet nothing works
I remove those ':' but it is now mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

I FOUND SOLUTION TURN VERSION 5

Answer (score 0):

There is no `:` at the end of an if statement in `pinescript`. Just remove those and don't forget to add a `strategy()` call in your code.

Comment: Thnx for the advice I added but it said: mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation' now . I checked the if sentence from documentation I couldn't find the solution.